# $2(1+abc)+\sqrt2(1+a^2)(1+b^2)(1+c^2)\ge(1+a)(1+b)(1+c)$ for real numbers $a,b,c$

Tags: inequality, translation-request

$a,b,c$ reel sayılar için ;

$$2(1+abc)+\sqrt2(1+a^2)(1+b^2)(1+c^2)\ge(1+a)(1+b)(1+c)$$

Olduğunu gösteriniz.

> **Translation:**<sup>1</sup> For real numbers $a,b,c$, show that:
>   $$2(1+abc)+\sqrt2(1+a^2)(1+b^2)(1+c^2)\ge(1+a)(1+b)(1+c)$$

<sup>1</sup><sub>With some help from Google translate</sub>

Comment: Turkish! Woohoo!

Comment: Note to the translator: The translation is true.

Answer (score 2):

let $$u=a+b+c,v=ab+bc+ac,w=abc$$
it suffices to show that
$$2(u^2+v^2+w^2-2wu-2v+1)\ge (u+v-w-1)^2$$
this inequality is equivalent to
$$u^2+v^2+w^2-2uv+2vw-2uw+2u-2v-2w+1\ge 0$$
or 
$$(u-v-w+1)^2\ge 0$$